# Excel Formula calculation incorrect

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, calculated-field

I created a calculator in Excel which looks pretty simple but has various formulas to get what I need however I'm notice that the Development Hours seems to have a different calculation in my Total Cost. I'm thinking it has something to do with decimal places but I researched and couldn't figure it out. Please see attached excel workbook.

[Excel Workbook Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCxUZeamlvORXlsUTJPYUtka0dIZEZGVEVDVjJwZWFsR0dJ/view?usp=docslist_api)

Development Hours: 22.6
Quality Check: 3.8
Project Management: 4.0
Cost per Hour: $150.00
TOTAL COST: $4,558.50

The actual total hours = 30.4 x $150.00 = $4560.00

the difference is $1.5 and not sure what is causing it to miscalculate. After calculating each category separately I determined it was the Dev Hours that's being miscalculated...

Comment: No. Simply calculating total hours for each category and multiplying by the cost which is $150.

Comment: It might be something to do with the type of the columns.
Choose the same data type for each column such as INTEGER and then try it.

Comment: @pnuts thats exactly the problem. thanks for pointing it out. the actual number was 22.59 but I only had it displaying for a single decimal which was rounding it. I will move forward with adding a Round function to correctly calculate and display the Total Cost. Go ahead and post your answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you ask about `= 30.4 x $150.00 = $4560.00` while in your attachment it says `22.5+3.8+4.0` which total to `30.3` not `30.4`. This tells that it is due to rounding.

To avoid this nest your values in the `round` function as:

```
=ROUND(your formulas and functions,1)
```

Note that you need to the `ROUND` function in the calculation cells for Development Hours, Quality Check Hours, and Project Management. If you'll do it just for the TOTAL COST calculation it will round the total cost value but it won’t calculate the rounded values.